# Can't initialize firebaseapp in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

Why would it not work? When I remove Firebase.initializeApp(); it works just fine. Everywhere I put it, it still doesn't work. I've tried to add it to every different place but it still didn't do anything.

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';


void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  Firebase.initializeApp();
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('123'),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red[600],
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            'hello mars!',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              letterSpacing: 2.0,
              color: Colors.grey[600],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('click'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red[600],
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
It should be something like this

Future<void> main()  async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Firebase.initializeApp();

   runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
      '/': (context) => LoadScreen(),
    },
  ));
}
```